# Image doesn't open throws ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, image, android-intent

The app is not able to open the Image using the following code, throws ActivityNotFoundException. What am I doing wrong?

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackage/" + R.drawable.sample_3), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Well formed question, +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Write below code line

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.yourappname/" + R.drawable.sample_3), "image/*");
```

instead of

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://mypackage/" + R.drawable.sample_3), "image/*");
```

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.android.yourApplicationName/" + R.drawable.sample_3), "image/*");
```

The yourApplicationName is the name of your application.

Your poblem is that you cant access mypackage directly.